# How can I prove that she cannot prove Or_commutative with only intro and apply?

Tags: coq

This question is related to a strategic game (bargaining, protocol, crypto,...) setting I investigate during holidays where players are Coq users.

Some of them have limited reasoning capabilities such as for example being only able to intro and apply an hypothesis or a lemma they were given.

Some others may have access to tauto.

In contrast, some rational players have unlimited reasoning capabilities and know other players’ type. Rational players can therefore reflect on what other players can prove or not and build their decision on it for their next move in the game.

Non-rational players have never access to CIC terms. I therefore restrict their Ltac grammar to a consistent but smaller fragment. I also restrict their list of atomic tactics. For example I would not allow a variant of apply with patterns or other which opens the door to CIC terms.

In the case of this question, it is simply a finite sequence of vanilla intro and apply tactics separated by a dot.

To summarize, a player’s type is defined by an Ltac grammar subset, a list of atomic tactics and a bag of lemmas given at the start of the game.

Here is the most verbose (smallest steps) proof of a tautology :

```
Lemma Or_commutative : forall P Q : Prop, P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.
Proof.
  intro P.
  intro Q.
  intro H.
  elim H.
  intro HP.
  right.
  apply HP.
  intro HQ.
  left.
  apply HQ.
Qed.
```

It is clear that we need elim, right and left tactics. Intro and apply are not sufficient.

Question : how can I prove that she cannot prove Or_commutative with only intro and apply ?

```
Goal cannot_prove_or_commutative_with_IAs : ????
Proof.
(* Here I want to show that no sequence of 
vanilla intro and apply tactics can solve the goal*)

(* I may define a structure of proof that is a sequence of intro and apply
and show that after step 3, it will fail or will not change the judgment.
How would I do that ? *)

(* Or should I go to the definitions of intro an apply and show that they cannot
handle OR terms ? *)

(* Or should I investigate plugins to reflect on tactics ? I heard of Mtac2 recently *)

Qed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To state this theorem, you need to define a Coq data type that captures the syntax of propositions you want to work with and associated inference rules.  This can encompass as much of Coq as you are willing to formalize.  To state your commutativity result, all we need is a simple propositional logic with disjunction and implication.

```
Inductive prop : Type :=
| Atomic  : nat -> prop (* Basic propositions *)
| Or      : prop -> prop -> prop
| Implies : prop -> prop -> prop.

Definition commutativity :=
  Implies (Or (Atomic 0) (Atomic 1)) (Or (Atomic 1) (Atomic 0)).
```

We can give a semantics to this logic, tying it back to the notion of truth that comes with Coq; `assn` is used to interpret atomic propositions:

```
Fixpoint sem (assn : nat -> Prop) (P : prop) :=
  match P with
  | Atomic x => assn x
  | Or P Q => sem assn P \/ sem assn Q
  | Implies P Q => sem assn P -> sem assn Q
  end.
```

Instead of working with tactics, it is easier and more commonplace to formalize proofs using an entailment relation, which states when a theorem can proved from a list of assumptions.  The following definition gives all the useful rules for the above fragment:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Inductive entails : list prop -> prop -> Type :=
| Ax : forall P G, In P G -> entails G P
| OrIL : forall G P Q, entails G P -> entails G (Or P Q)
| OrIR : forall G P Q, entails G Q -> entails G (Or P Q)
| OrE  : forall G P Q R,
           entails (P :: G) R ->
           entails (Q :: G) R ->
           entails G (Or P Q) ->
           entails G R
| ImpliesI : forall G P Q,
               entails (P :: G) Q ->
               entails G (Implies P Q)
| ImpliesE : forall G P Q,
               entails G (Implies P Q) ->
               entails G P ->
               entails G Q.
```

It should be possible to prove a soundness theorem, saying that the proofs built from these inference rules yield valid theorems:

```
Theorem soundness assn G P :
  entails G P ->
  Forall (sem assn) G -> sem assn P.
```

Only allowing `intros` and `apply` would amount to ruling out uses of `OrE`, which we can enforce with a boolean predicate:

```
Fixpoint no_destruct {G P} (pf : entails G P) : bool :=
  match pf with
  | Ax _ _ _ => true
  | OrIL _ _ _ pf => no_destruct pf
  | OrIR _ _ _ pf => no_destruct pf
  | OrE _ _ _ _ _ _ _ => false
  | ImpliesI _ _ _ pf => no_destruct pf
  | ImpliesE _ _ _ pf1 pf2 => no_destruct pf1 && no_destruct pf2
  end.
```

You can finally state your metatheorem: any proof of commutativity must use the `OrE` rule:

```
Theorem no_commutativity (pf : entails nil commutativity) : no_destruct pf = false.
```

On top of my head, I do not know exactly how this proof would proceed. One possibility could be to give your restricted logic a non-standard interpretation which validates all inference rules, except for `OrE`, and where `Or` is not commutative.

Comment: The amount of maths I need for the games I consider is actually more involved than Prop logic. I need Predicate logic and Real analysis. For example, one of the games is the Rubinstein bargaining model. That’s why I wanted to stay as close to tactics/Ltac as possible. I do not see how I would be able to follow your advice. Nevertheless I am really astonished by how fast & far you went with your answer on commutativity.

Comment: Though more complex, you could also formalize higher-order logic with this approach. This is how the Coq manual defines CIC, for instance (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html). I don't know of any developments that have tried formalizing the semantics of a proof system through tactics, but I suspect that it would be more complex than formalizing an entailment relation. In any case, you will need to formalize _some_ proof system in Coq to reason about provability; otherwise you won't be able to state your result.

Comment: Thx Arthur. By the way, there is an error on Ax constructor in entails definition.

Comment: I am not sure about your OrE constructor in entails. It does not deal with P being in G but not at head. I would better see : In P G ->
           In Q G ->
           entails G R ->
           entails G (Or P Q) ->
           entails (List.remove P (List.remove Q G)) G R. But it also cannot make it because I do not have equality on prop type.

Comment: @FZed Typically, proof systems such as the one above validate an _exchange_ property, which says that if `entails G P` is derivable, then so is `entails G' P` for any permutation `G'` of `G`. With exchange, it is possible to implement the rule you are looking for as a derived principle rather than a primitive one.